# Apache cannot load weblogic module

Tags: java, oracle, apache, weblogic12c

Experiencing this error while trying to restart apache:

> ```
> httpd:syntax error on line 168 of httpd.conf:Cannot load modules/mod_wl_24.so into server:libopmsecure.so:cannot open shared
>  object file:no such file or directory:
>  \#168 of httpd.conf LoadModule weblogic_module modules/mod_wl-24.so.
> ```

Comment: The error message says, that it can't find your module you want to use. Therefore you have to install it if it is needed in your project.

Comment: I have that module in my modules directory.

Comment: I found the solution for it, copied all lib files from WLSplugin/linux/lib to my apache/lib dir, then it did work  fine.

Comment: Answered to make it clearer if anybody else comes looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You found the solution for it!

> The solution is to **copy all lib files from `WLSplugin/linux/lib` 
>   to your `apache/lib` directory**

Then it will work fine.